Shrink image in a container when screen is small
This is the expected result :

Stackblitz available here
The rules are :

I have a square image
I want to add white margins on the sides in order to get a 16/9 rectangle
I want to add a purple background with padding + text information
The preferred width of the white area is 300px
If the screen is smaller, the image should shrink but preserve the 16/9 ratio, like this :




.host-container {
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  height: 400px;
}

.large {
  width: 500px;
}

.small {
  width: 200px;
}

.card {
  background-color: #8e44ad;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 1rem;
  /*
   * I have to use 
   * "display: inline-block" on large screen
   * "display: block" on small screen
   */
  /*display: block;*/
  display: inline-block;
}

.img-16-9 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /*
   * Here, I have to use :
   * "width: 300px" on large screens
   * "width: clamp(10px, 300px, 100%)" on small screens
   * but a clamp on small screens
   */
  /*width: clamp(10px, 300px, 100%);*/
  width: 300px;
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  background-color: white;
}

.img-square {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/3135/3135715.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}
<!-- host-container simulates the screen width -->
<div class="host-container large">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="img-16-9">
      <div class="img-square"></div>
    </div>
    <h1>J. Doe</h1>
  </div>
</div>



Problem : I struggle with the width of the white area :

If I declare it as 300px, the image is fine when the screen is large but the image won't shrink when the screen is small
But if I declare it as clamp(10px, 300px, 100%), the image will shrink on small screens but it won't take 300px when the screen is larger. The width will be decided by the width of the text and not the image :


It seems that the browser cannot interpret the width of the image element when clamp is used, resulting in a mess with the width of the purple card element

Related documentation to read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio "At least one of the box's sizes needs to be automatic"

@MarkSchultheiss I have read it but I don't understand. The height of the image is not set so it is auto by default, right ?

Set the width on the card element instead


.host-container {
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  height: 400px;
}

.large {
  width: 500px;
}

.small {
  width: 200px;
}

.card {
  background-color: #8e44ad;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 300px; /* or calc(300px + 2rem) */
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.img-16-9 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  background-color: white;
}

.img-square {
  background-image: url(https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/3135/3135715.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}
<!-- host-container simulates the screen width -->
<div class="host-container large">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="img-16-9">
      <div class="img-square"></div>
    </div>
    <h1>J. Doe</h1>
  </div>
</div>




Yes, that would work with width: clamp(10px, 300px, calc(100% - 2rem)); on the card. I would still prefer to set the size on the image and not on the card

@ArnaudDenoyelle you are setting the display of the card to be inline-block so it means the card need to get the width not the image.
